# Best method to mount electric motor for chain drive for industrial machinery

Tags: motors, industrial-engineering, chain

I want to use this electric motor to run an industrial machine via ANSI roller chain. In the images most of the machine is not visible, only the sprocket on the input shaft and a bit of the relevant framing, along with the motor with its corresponding sprocket is visible. The framing will be made from some 1-5/8 strut channel. I would like some recommendations about how to mount the motor and tension the chain. The motor has mounting points for M8x1.25 bolts. Should I use ready made angle brackets, or attempt to mount it to a custom made mounting plate out of perhaps 1/4 steel and then tension the chain by adjust the position of the motor with a tensioning screw in order to not need an idler/tensioner.  Any recommendations on my idea?

[image: machine layout]

[image: Motor mounting bolt pattern]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much about the application but fixed wheel bikes work quite robustly without a tensioning gear, maybe you can look at how they work.

In general terms it seems like all the options that you have suggested are reasonable, have you considered using methods such as a Pugh Matrix to help you?

For example, it seems like using ready made brackets might have better quality control and might improve cost but maybe not be as ideal in size as making custom made ones.
Procureability is another one, can you find the components that you describe? are tensioning screws more easily procured than a separate gear?

Answer (score 0):

Going by your diagram, I would place the motor so it will be above the two horizontal rails and use them as a sliding support for a bracket holding the motor.

The bracket needs to be sufficiently strong to resist flexing / bending and be able to provide adjustment.

Comment: Do you think ready made brackets may exist, or should I just have one machined

Comment: @sebastian323 if you can make the framing, you should be able to make the brackets...